# Awesome-TypeScript-Loader error on webpack rebuild

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run "npm start" webpack build everything successfully. When I then go and change a file and save, it attempt to rebuild and I get the following error

```
C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\instance.ts:334
        const changedFiles = Object.keys(mtimes).map(toUnix);
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\instance.ts:334:37)
    at next (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:140:14)
    at Compiler.compilerInvalid (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\Shared.js:144:5)
    at next (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:140:14)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\CachePlugin.js:32:5)
    at next (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:140:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\watch-mode.ts:12:13)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)
    at Watching._go (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:43:16)
    at Watching.invalidate (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:121:8)
    at Watching.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:106:8)
    at EventEmitter.watcher.once (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeWatchFileSystem.js:44:4)
    at EventEmitter.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at EventEmitter._onTimeout (C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\PTCCompass\Web.Angular\node_modules\watchpack\lib\watchpack.js:139:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

Here is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.6",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@vaadin/angular2-polymer": "^1.0.0",
    "ag-grid": "~8.0.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "~8.0.1",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "~8.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.1",
    "bootstrap-tour": "^0.11.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "icheck": "^1.0.2",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "lz-string": "^1.4.4",
    "metismenu": "2.0.2",
    "nestable": "^0.2.0",
    "ng2-modal": "0.0.24",
    "ng2-tag-input": "^0.7.9",
    "pace": "0.0.4",
    "pace-progress": "^1.0.2",
    "primeng": "^1.1.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "~5.1.0",
    "summernote": "^0.8.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.6",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.38",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "1.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.1",
    "ngc-webpack": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.0",
    "parse5": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.2.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "3.0.0"
  },
```

The change that started this was reverting angular back to 2.4.6 from 2.4.7. On 2.4.7 I was getting an error about Token is null, so reverted back to 2.4.6 which fixed that, but now every time I save a file my webpack server crashes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the same issue and tracked it down to watchpack being updated to version 1.3.0.  Create a shrinkwrap file using "npm shrinkwrap --dev" and change the watchpack version to 1.2.1 and re-run npm install. That fixed it for me.

Comment: thanks! Not sure how anyone is supposed to figure stuff like thus out without help? How did you track this down?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I get the same error using ts-loader, but only when testing with karma.

Comment: Like @Litz said, watchpack is the culprit - I added "watchpack": "1.2.1" to my package.json and re-installed. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect that was identified from us while deprecating a property on [watchpack](http://github.com/webpack/watchpack). However we didn't realize that people were relying on the private api endpoints. Therefore, we should have just rolled it back. Keep an eye on the tracking issue:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/479

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue using webpack 2.

```
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.4",
"ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
"webpack": "^2.2.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
```

Updating `ts-loader` => 2.0.1 and `awesome-typescript-loader` => 3.0.7 has resolved this issue for me. I can't speak for webpack 1.

Comment: Updated to those versions and same issue.